# If $\alpha \in BV[a, b]$, $\int_a^b fd\alpha$ exists and $\alpha$ is continuous at $x \in [a, b]$, $F(y) = \int_a^y f d\alpha$ is continuous at $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\alpha \in BV[a, b]$, $|f(y)| \le M < \infty$ for $y \in [a, b]$, $\int_a^b fd\alpha$ exists and $\alpha$ is continuous at $x \in [a, b]$. I try to bound $|F(x+h) - F(x)| = |\int_x^{x+h} f d \alpha| \le \int_x^{x+h} |f d \alpha| \le M \int_x^{x+h} |d\alpha| = M V_x^{x+h} \alpha$. The problem is, I do not know that $\beta(y) = V_a^y \alpha$ is continuous at $x$, so I cannot conclude that this expression goes to zero as $h \to 0$. Showing that it is continuous at $x$ seems to require a stronger assumption, such as $\alpha$ being locally absolutely continuous at $x$. How can I proceed?

Comment: Do you have further information about $f$ ? (continuity e.g. would make life easy)

Comment: No, f is not necessarily continuous at $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\alpha$ has bounded variation and let $\alpha$ be continuous at  $x\in [a,b)$.
Then $V_x^u=V_x^u(\alpha)$ is a decreasing (positive) function as $u\rightarrow x^+$, whence has a limit $\ell$. 
Suppose $\ell>0$ and let $\epsilon>0$. For $u>x$ close enough to $x$ we have $\ell\leq V_x^u<\ell+\epsilon$ and also $\sup_{x<v<u} |\alpha(v)-\alpha(x)|<\epsilon$ (by continuity of $\alpha$).

By the definition of the variation:

$$ \ell\leq  V_x^u = \sup_{x<v<u} \left( |\alpha(x)-\alpha(v)| + V_v^u \right) \leq \epsilon + \sup_{x<v<u} \left(  V_v^u \right) $$ 
Thus, there is $x<v<u$ so that $V_v^u\geq \ell-\epsilon$ and consequently 
$$ V_x^v =V_x^u-V_v^u\leq 2\epsilon$$
As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we see that $\ell=\lim_{v\rightarrow x^+} V_x^v=0$. 
Using the same argument for the left limit we see that $V_x^u$ is continuous at $u=x$ which implies the wanted bound.

Comment: The whole problem is to show that the variation function is continuous at $x$, so I don't think this answer is complete.